# How can a cherry-pick or merge a commit with regard to a certain beginning?

Tags: git

1. checkout branchA from master(which is at commitA), and add some commits to branchA
2. other contributors merged serveral PRs into master
3. checkout branchB from master(which is at commitB)
4. repeat the following operation several times:

   1. add some commits into branchB
   2. merge newest master(which is at commitB1, commitB2, ... commitBN) into branchB
      This operation is quite common, since GitHub provide a button "Update branch".

Now, if we diff branchB with commitBN, the result will include exactly branchB's modifications to master.

However, how can I apply these changes to branchA? I come up with several ideas:

1. git cherry-pick all branchB's commits(not including those to merge newest master). This is ugly, since there are many merge commits.
2. git diff branchB with commitBN as a patch file, and then apply this patch. However, `git apply` is easy to fail with "patch does not apply" in this case.
3. I can't merge/rebase, since I don't want commitB1, commitB2, ... commitBN. What I need is to "replay" what I have done to branchB on branchA again.

I think no one is neat. The first one is cost lots of time, I would rather pick it manually. The second one is just like a automated script which is prone to fail. The third one will result in many conflicts which is irrelevent with my code.

I think conflicts are acceptable, but those irrelevant conflicts are not acceptable.

Comment: Is `git checkout branchA; git rebase branchB` not an option?

Comment: @eftshift0 No, because there are too much conflicts if I rebase

Comment: Then what you should do is merge.

Comment: @eftshift0 Merge is not acceptable, because I don't want to pick commitB1, commitB2, ... commitBN

Comment: You cannot reject obvious and correct approaches merely because there are conflicts. Of _course_ there are conflicts. If you are not willing to deal with conflicts, don't use Git. Conflicts are not bad! They are a normal part of using Git.

Comment: I would also say that this sentence in the question, _This operation is quite common, since GitHub provide a button "Update branch",_ exposes a serious flaw in the team's working approach. Just because it is possible to do a thing, doesn't mean one should do it. It sounds to me like this must apply to your repo: "The base branch requires branches to be up to date before merging or the setting to always suggest updating branches is enabled" I would advise turning off that setting, so that the Update Branch button doesn't even appear. It is causing you trouble.

Comment: @matt Sometimes I have to update branch, to adopt a bugfix of some irrelevant code.

Comment: @matt And I will show you the problem I met here. Consider branchB is `CalvinNeo:tikv-fast-add-peer` in this [pr](https://github.com/tikv/tikv/pull/14043), and consider branchA is `ldz/adapt-raft-engine-uni-ps` in this [pr](https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-engine-ext/pull/240). And you can find why rebase and merge does not work here. You can verify merge-base and see tikv-fast-add-peer and ldz/adapt-raft-engine-uni-ps are all derived from tikv/master

Comment: Hmm, but they are not merging into the same branch.

Comment: @matt I don't get your point

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by

```
git format-patch --stdout commitBN.. branchB > diff.patch
# checkout to branchA
git am -3 < diff.patch
```

Though there are still some conflicts due to some squash merging before. The number of conflicts is limited.

Comment: That's the equivalent of `git checkout branchA; git cherry-pick commitBN..branchB`.